# Why the input function in Pycharm does not work when inputting strings?

Tags: python

```
name = input('what is your name? ')
print('hi ' + name)
```

The output shows:

```
what is your name? John
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xx/PycharmProjects/Tutorial/basic_tutorial.py", line 1, in <module>
    name = input('what is your name? ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'John' is not defined
```

It is not working when inputting John without quotes. However, I believe the syntax is not wrong in Pycharm. Anyone knows why?

Comment: This does not have anything to do with Pycharm. You are simply using Python 2 and there `input` is equivalent to `eval(input(...))` in Python 3. You should either use `raw_input`, or **ALOT** more preferably, move to Python 3!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure if you are using Python 3 as an interpreter. Python 2 has some other syntax for input as far as I remember.